Background tasks in Ionic Vue
I have a list of motivational messages from local sqlite db created during application installation. I need to display these messages one at a time anywhere within the user’s screen. As it seems, I need a background task to run the process to display these messages, additionally, I need the messages to display on top of other apps within the user’s device of course after getting a permission from them. I am using Ionic Capacitor, is this something achievable with Ionic Capacitor? Has anyone here ever done something like this before? Are there any plugins you would recommend? Thank you in advance. I already have some starter code for the messages Vue component, if you may want t o see it, I can gladly share it.
I have tried looking out for any plugin that can easily help me achieve this to no avail.

you can use Local Notifications.
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications
